# Search Bar hide extra UITableView rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using search bar example from [Search Bar With UITableView](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-seachbar-to-tableview-ios7). I tried to hide empty table rows using:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

It hides extra rows in normal state of table view with default data. But when I search for something, empty rows show up as well. Why is this happening? How do I fix this?
[image: Table View without searching anything][image: Table View when searching]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The searchDisplayController has its own table view that you can access with `self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView`. You need to add a footer view to that table view also. Use of a UISearchDisplayController is depreciated in iOS 8; you should be using UISearchController now, unless you need to support iOS 7.